# Combining Stone Weirstrass theorem with approximations of $L^p$ spaces, is it possible?

Tags: real-analysis, compactness, approximation-theory

Consider the following version of the Stone-Weierstrass Approximation theorem (from [Royden - Real Analysis](https://s2pnd-matematika.fkip.unpatti.ac.id/wp-content/uploads/2019/03/Real-Analysis-4th-Ed-Royden.pdf))

> **The Stone-Weierstrass Approximation Theorem** Let $X$ be a compact Hausdorff space. Suppose $\mathcal{A}$ is an algebra of continuous real-valued functions on $X$ that separates points in $X$ and contains the constant functions. Then $\mathcal{A}$ is dense in $C(X)$.

Consider also the following approximation theorem from [enter link description here](https://59clc.files.wordpress.com/2011/01/real-and-complex-analysis.pdf)

> **3.14 Theorem** For $1 \leq p < \infty$, $C_c(X)$ is dense in $L^p(\mu)$.

There's a key difference between the two theorems, in the Stone-Weierstrass theorem $X$ is a *compact Hausdorff space* while in Rudin's $X$ is a *locally compact Hausdorff space*.

This which makes me suspect it's probably not possible to approximate elements of $L^p(\mu)$ with element of some algebra in $C_c(X)$ (when $X$ is only locally compact).

However if $X$ is compact then is also locally compact so in that case it can work, but I wonder what if is just locally compact but not compact.

Comment: There is a locally compact version of Stone Weierstrass Theorem: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stone%E2%80%93Weierstrass_theorem

Comment: A proof of that result? My references don't seem to have it.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2988876/an-application-of-a-variation-of-the-stone-weierstrass-theorem